# When don't we use "__all__" in ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is just my curiosity but I will be very happy if anyone answers my question.

I am using `Django Rest Framework` but I'm a beginner. In serializers.py, I use `ModelSerializer` and `"all"` to `fields` attribute.
This is an example.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

And then, I just thought

**when don't we use `"__all__"` in `serializers.py`??**

As long as we create `models.py` in advance, I think we usually use all fields in each `Model`.
I would like you to teach me when we omit specific fields that come from each `Model`.

Thank you.

Comment: "We" generally never use `__all__`, cause anything you add to the model, will end up in the serializer, including secret information like password fields.

Comment: If you do not want all fields to be included, for example (hashed) passwords, sensitive data, access control, etc.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that. Make more sense. I just came up with a new question. If we use some fields of all fields in `Model`, how do we store information of the rest of fields? Perhaps, does `Serializer` work for only when the server passes some information as JSON to the client? Honestly, I don't fully understand how `Serializer` works.

Comment: A serializer doesn't store anything. It transforms from one format to another, in this case from native python types to JSON. But if you mean how to update all fields: some fields have defaults, auto generated or provided as extra fields on the serializer and then transformed to be saved on the model or determined from the request, such as the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the second question is a bit harder to explain in a comment:

> If we use some fields of all fields in Model, how do we store information of the rest of fields?

Various cases:

Fields with defaults:

```py
class Log(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ('message',)
```

For autogenerated, think user profile models via the post_save signal or calculated fields:

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField()

class OrderLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    product = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        fields = ('quantity', 'product', 'order')
```

In this case, the product is a primary key for a product. The serializer will have a save method that looks up the product and put it's name and price on the OrderLine. This is standard practice as you cannot reference a product in your orders, else your orders would change if you change (the price of) your product.

And derived from request:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.TextField()

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('post',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = BlogPost(**validated_data)
        instance.author = self.context['request'].user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

This is pretty much the common cases.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that. To be honest, it's a little bit difficult to me so I will keep on studying in order to fully understand what you taught me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases, but I think the two main ones are:

- When you don't want all fields to be returned by the serializer.
- When you need some method of the serializer to know its fields. In such case, you should traverse `fields` array, but it doesn't work if you use `__all__`, only if you have an actual list of fields.

Comment: A method can just access fields attribute or `get_fields()` method. Extending a serializer's Meta class is a different story.

Comment: Of course there are several ways for doing so, but depending on the context, you have to choose the best suited one